# Running SonarQube Ant task without source code

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, jacoco

I have problem with SonarQube Ant task. I need to get only integration tests coverage (without running unit tests, static code analysis, etc.) and send it to my SonarQube server. I have externally generated `jacoco_it.exec` file and already compiled and compressed the `.jar files`.

I have some questions about it:

1. Can I make it without source code? How do I avoid:

   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'org.demo:demo': sonar.sources
2. How do I use the `.jar` file in `sonar.binaries`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarQube is not a multi-purpose reporting tool. It is all about the inspection of the **source code**, so you must absolutely specify where your source code is located.